# The right way to pass a input to the typescript file

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I know about this way to send a input from the user to the typescript (angular) :

```
    <form >
    <input #input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputColor" (input)="sendInput(input.value)" />
    </form>
```

But its looking for not very effective , i create a reference to the DOM with `#input` and after that send the `input.value` .

After all, I am very confused about the `input.value` does he refer to `#input` or to to `(input)=...;`.

Bottom line, is there a more efficient way to pass the value the user puts into the box, into the typescript file and then use it for another tag in the HTML file?

For example the user put a size of text and i want to use with the use on another tag on HTML ....

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well, you re looking for $event ?

```
<input #input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputColor" (input)="sendInput($event)" />
```

typescript side:

```
sendInput($event) {
  console.log('input value:', $event.data);
}
```

But $event.data will only contain the last typed char, is it what you re looking for ?.

EDIT:
With (input), you can have the content of input in $event.target.value:

```
<input #input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputColor"
(input)="sendInput($event.target.value)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First of you you have used ngModel with input, so your inputcolor will have that value, and you can use it. But if you want it passed to a method you can do it like :-

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputColor" (change)="sentInput($event.target.value) />
```

Change event will be fired as soon as user is done typing and click anywhere else.

then have a sendInput method in ts to copy received value in a property

```
public sendInput(value) {
  this.data = value;
}
```

**OR**

If you don't need two way binding, you can use ngModel for one way binding as well like :-

```
<input type="text" (ngModel)="inputColor" />
```

After this typescript value change will not impact, only change in template will be reflected in typescript variable.

Comment: The ngModel is the connect between the HTML to Typescript  and the Typescript  to HTML , and $event.target.value is allow me to delete the #input?

Comment: Can you explain the (change)=? this is a save world in anguler like (input)= ?

Comment: in his case, it would be better to use (keyup), or (input), if he wants the value each time the user is typing.

Comment: depends on you usecase, if you want value as he types use keyup, if you want only after he is done typing use change.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use angular input inside a html input tag, which is not possible.

You need to use a keyboard event handler like "keyup", "keydown"...

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputColor" (keyup)="sendInput($event)" />
```

Comment: "trying to use angular input inside a html input tag, which is not possible" why not ? i doing this all the time and its working ...

Comment: Feel free to share an example, because the only "input/ouput" I use for inputs is ngModel, then it's all about the event handlers